# How to get all column data with sum of a column from mongodb using 'groupBy' in laravel?

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4

I want to get sum of a column with other column data from mongodb using 'group by' in laravel. But i am getting only a numeric value. Like there is a collection called 'templates'. And my model in laravel is 'TemplateUser'.  In that collection i have 5 column. '_id', 'user_id', 'template_id', 'visitor', 'subscriber'. Here template id will be same in different row. I want sum(visitor),sum(subscriber) and template_id group by 'template_id'. But i can not get the value. I am using 'jenssegers/laravel-mongodb' package in laravel.

I tried the following code

```
$get_data = TemplatesUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->_id)->groupBy('template_id')->sum('visitor');
```

I only get `int(23)` as a result.

Comment: Providing some code would be helpful to understand your problem, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I added my sample code. And the output result.